# Check when data is returned in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a method which gets data from session storage. I am now trying to check when the data is available before using it. How can I do this. Here is my code.

service.ts

```
  getStoredData() {
    const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('myData'));
    return data;
  }
```

component.ts

In my constructor I have

```
const storage = this._storage.getStoredData();
```

I would like to wait until the data is ready as it currently console.logs undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `polling` and when the data is ready, just stop polling:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

dataReady = false;

constructor() {
  const subscription = interval(1000).subscribe(n => {
        console.log("Counting " + n);
        if(this._storage.getStoredData() !== undefined) {
          subscription.unsubscribe();
          this.dataReady = true;
        }
    });
}
```

and use `dataReady`

Answer (score 1):

To make sure your data is present, you shall use [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

You can see a simple example of how to use it in this stackblitz example:
[How to use resolve](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reading-data-from-resolver?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Note that you can use your service inside the Resolver and then use it in the component.